# C#: determine if a class has already been initialized

Tags: c#, reflection

I have many classes in an assembly that I can't or don't want to modify. At some point of runtime, I want to know which of them have already been "initialized": static initializer (= static constructor) has run.

Is there a way to do it with reflection or something else?

For information, not every class in an assembly is initialized when the assembly is loaded. This can be easily observed with this piece of code:

```
public static class Foo
{
    static Foo() { MainClass.Value = "Something"; }
    public static void DoSomething() { Thread.Sleep(100); }
}

public static class MainClass
{
    public static string Value = "Nothing";

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
        Foo.DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine(Value);
    }
}
```

Displays:

```
Nothing
Something
```

Comment: "Is there a way to do it with reflection or something else?" No, unless you introduce a flag that you set in the static constructor. But do all your classes even **have** such a constructor?

Comment: Please read the question entirely.

Comment: @BenoitSanchez: sounds like a XY-question. What are you actually trying to do, why you think you need to know that? If you need to know if your class is initialized(so something in it is ready to use), you have to introduce a flag that is set in the initialization method.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well... tools such as WinDbg / SOS can list all the instances of a class. There might be might something here to investigate... although it might more complicated than just put a simple flag :)

Comment: Agree Tim, this seems like a really bad idea. Usually you shouldn´t rely on the static constructor in order to "initialize" something. In particular when there is also a normal constructor. In this case, when would you call an instance call "initialized"? When the statzic ctor ran? When the instance ctor also ran? What if your class has only one or even none at all? You see there´s no general term for "initialized".

Comment: Another funny fact is, that even if there **was** a way to indicate this, you´d shoot yourself in your own foot, because a static constructor is invoked the very first time you use the class in any way. Using reflection to access the class will therefor **also** run the static constructor, if not already done. So if you ask your class if it was initialized (whatever that actually means), it´ll allways answers: "yes".

Comment: If you try to read the flag, of course the initializer will run. However Type.GetType("...Foo") for example does not run the initializer (I've checked).

Comment: The profiling API allows you to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/bb384547(v=vs.90) . Although it cannot be used in C# and must be implemented using C++.

Comment: The closest equivalent to what you describe is the Static constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors And the rules for those are clear: "It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."

Comment: @Christopher: you really haven't read the question ;-)

Comment: @Kzrystof - Yeah, I think that's the only likely route. Depends on whether that's "something else" enough for the OP. E.g. you can work out whether the static initializer has been JITted which should be a strong indication that it's been called.

Comment: @Jevgeni. Your comment is a potential answer.

Comment: @HimBromBeere cool comment about the "Another funny fact is," It reminds me of Scrödingers Cat. If you open the box to see whether the cat is dead, the cat dies ...

Comment: @HimBromBeere - well, you need to spend a bit of time thinking about this and realize you want/need a separate class that is just told by other classes "I've been initialized" and so has the inspectable state separate from the classes of interest.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Not true. As you can see. Accessing flag does not trigger initializer to run: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFVANhQCZCB2JAbxyXpQLRLgBYkBZAQwEsoAKAJQ06DMWgCc/AMIA6AGIAbLgHMAzrICSUHsB5dFPAF4BTMAHUuagErRBWbGLFyOQh04aSZC5eq069A2MzSxs7dwYAXxxo3CZyaRFHT2IkaSEkj3ovACJtXX1DUzAkAHcrJEgoWRz7UQ8lVQ18wKKQq1soJABeJGBIEwj6WPEmVLZODOokEc8xlnJG9Uys/EISACMAey3FJBbC4IsO6CGZmJwgA

Comment: @PetSerAl Your class `C` constructor isn´t called because you don´t use the class `C` but the class `C.Flags`. A nested class is more like a class in another namespace in this sense. So the correct class´ name is `C.Flags`. Thios class has no relation to `C`-class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes I know all that, and that allows me construct the case where accessing flag does not trigger initializer to run. Which counter your statement: *So if you ask your class if it was initialized (whatever that actually means), it´ll allways answers: "yes".*

Answer (score 0):

As said [HimBromBeere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2528063/himbrombeere), and as confirmed in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors),

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

So you need to use your class once, a property, a method, whatever, to initialize it... You have no control on it, you can't call it programatically and, if you want to know if the static constructor has been used, you'll use the class, so it could be called at this point...

As said [Rango](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/rango), you can use a flag in your constructor, if you really absolutly need to know...